# Initiating Jquery makes Safari Crash

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari, flexslider

My website is working great in Chrome, FF & IE but I recently noticed my slider doesnt show on Ipad or Iphone and it totally freezes/crashes on Safari (Windows 8). I have managed to work out that it is the following bit of Jquery in the footer that is causing the issue, but i can't see how or why. I only know it is causing the issue because when i comment it out - the site doesnt crash Safari. Can anyone see why this might be happening. Am i doing something wrong?

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){   

$('.mentioncontent a').attr ('target', '_blank');   

$('.flexslider1').flexslider({
     animation: "slide",
     animationLoop: false
});

$('.flexslider2').flexslider({
     animation: "slide",
    animationLoop: false
});

$('.flexslider3').flexslider({
     animation: "slide",
     animationLoop: false
});

$('.fancybox-media').fancybox({

             onClose: function() {
            jwplayer('my-video').stop();
        }
});

});

</script>
```

Comment: When you say "crash Safari", what do you really mean?  What actually happens? What errors show in the log?

Comment: How do i find the log on my Windows 8 laptop? Basically, the loading bar at the top of Safari gets 75% towards the end, then the site just crashes Safari. I can debug with FF, etc but cant work out how to work th eissue out when Safari has crashed on me.

Comment: Please describe what "crashes Safari" actually means?  Are you running Safari on Windows 8?  I'm not even aware that is a supported application/configuration any more (last updated in 2012).  Here's Apple's info on how to get to the web inspector in Safari https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/GettingStarted/GettingStarted.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007874-CH2-SW1

Comment: But i can't get to the inspector or anything because as soon as i view my site in safari, the page becomes unusable and i have to shut down Safari using the task manager.

Comment: By crash i mean that the site doesnt load in the safari window - it becomes totally unusable before the site has fully loaded. And then i cant click on any buttons or use the browser at all - meaning i have to force a safari restart on my machine.

Comment: Well, there's nothing obviously wrong with the code you've included in your question so you'll have to show us the rest of the page.  I personally don't even run Safari on Windows any more as it isn't an interesting platform to test as Apple has essentially droppped it.  So, I'd suggest trying Safari on an Apple device (iPhone, iPad, Mac computer) and see if the problem still exists there.

Comment: Are there no issues in Chrome, Firefox and IE?

Comment: ok, well the issue is the same issue that is causing the slider to not display on ipad and iphone i think so if i can sort this issue - im sure i'll fix the ipad/iphone problems.

Comment: No issues at all in Chrome, firefox or ie. Can i privately send you a link?

Comment: Here's the page: http://goo.gl/zCGaXb

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63133/discussion-between-dmt-and-jfriend00).